# Loop through files of given type in a directory

Tags: python, file

I have a directory of .jpg files I need to loop through, and it has to be invoked from the command line with `python program.py directory/*.jpg`
The code I have only finds the first image in that folder.

```
import sys, glob

arg = sys.argv[1]
files = glob.glob(arg)
for fname in files:
    print(fname)
```

It only prints out the name of the first file in the folder, when I print the length of the list files, it returns 1.

Edit: print(arg) is printing the name of the first file, rather than the directory, how do I fix this, sys.argv[1] should be the directory/*.jpg no?

Comment: Not much to be said without looking at your directory/directory structure

Comment: At the risk of asking a foolish question, are you absolutely sure that there's more than 1 jpg in that dir?

Comment: May be `walk()` method of `os` module can help you.

Comment: There are 25 jpgs in that dir, I'm almost completely sure it's not a problem with the directory/structure

Comment: What is the output of `ls directory/*.jpg` ? What's the directory name where the files reside?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find all files in a directory with extension .txt in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964681/find-all-files-in-a-directory-with-extension-txt-in-python)

Comment: @ventsyv ls directory/*.jpg gives 

directory/0606163.jpg directory/060611231.jpg etc. as I expected

the program is in the directory that contains the directory of the images, is this the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing wrong with your code, but you are not escaping your wildcards correctly. 
Try running your script as:

```
python program.py directory/\*.jpg
```

When you run `python program.py directory/*.jpg` the shell expands the wildcard resulting in `argv[1]` to be the first filename that matched, thus resulting in glob being called not with `<directory>/*.jpg` but with `<directory>/<firstFile>`

You can easily see that if you add `print arg` before the glob call.

For example, if you directory contains two files, 0606163.jpg and 060611231.jpg

`python program.py directory/*.jpg` will be equivalent to `python program.py directory/0606163.jpg directory/060611231.jpg`

Comment: Thanks, this works. I also solved it by simply putting the sys.argv call in the loop.

    `for fname in sys.argv[1:]:
        print (fname)`

Comment: @Chaz If  you rely on shell variable extension then no need to call glob.

Answer (score 0):

I personally use [`os.walk()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk).

```
import os
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('YOUR_PATH_OR_SYS_ARG_HERE'):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.jpg'):
            print(file)
```

Comment: Does not support wildcards.

Comment: @ventsyv No wildcards used, the code works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `listdir` perhaps?

```
import os
jpgFiles = os.listdir('your/path/here')

for file in jpgFiles:
        print(file)
```